# creating a table variable in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

How can i get the alias 'value' from PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS into the balance from PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_ID?

```
SELECT SUM(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) value 
FROM PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS b  
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID 

UPDATE TABLE PF_BANKACCOUNTS_BALANCE 
SET BALANCE =  value 
WHERE b.ACCOUNT_ID =  PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE PF_BANKACCOUNTS_BALANCE
   SET BALANCE =
          (SELECT SUM (TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) VALUE
             FROM PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS b
            WHERE b.ACCOUNT_ID = PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated UPDATE statement or MERGE:

```
UPDATE PF_BANKACCOUNTS_BALANCE b
   SET BALANCE =
          (SELECT SUM (TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)
             FROM PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS t
            WHERE b.ACCOUNT_ID = t.ACCOUNT_ID)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS t
WHERE b.ACCOUNT_ID = t.ACCOUNT_ID)
/


MERGE INTO PF_BANKACCOUNTS_BALANCE b
USING (SELECT SUM(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) VALUE, ACCOUNT_ID
             FROM PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS t
            WHERE GROUP BY t.ACCOUNT_ID) s
ON (b.ACCOUNT_ID = s.ACCOUNT_ID)            
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET b.BALANCE = s.VALUE
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PL/SQL is quit easy.

```
declare
value number;
begin
select sum(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) into value from PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS b  group by ACCOUNT_ID;
 set BALANCE = value where b.ACCOUNT_ID =  PF_BANKACCOUNTS_TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_ID;
end;
/
```